# Node.js - Append JSON file without using FS lib - require('fs)

Tags: javascript, node.js

I can read JSON file from:

```
const json = require('file.json')
console.log(json)
```

It's ok!

But now, I'd like to append values in file.json, without do require('fs')/writeFileSync.

Is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it's not possible to update a file without using the `fs` module (AFAIK, at least).

But you can do something like this:

```js
const fs = require("fs");

const json = require('file.json');
console.log(json);

// Update json

fs.writeFile('file.json', JSON.stringify(json), (err, data) => {
  //handle result
});
```